# Check truncated tuple values in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples

```
In [142]: mylist=[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.769883), (-0.01435677, 1.7573411), (-0.3796871, -0.40361387), (-0.27704585, -1.7006601), (-0.26976547, -2.6480746), (-0.27020714, -3.0438666), (-0.2759932, -3.638946), (-0.28580084, -4.182567), (-0.29590216, -4.5594716), (-0.31486654, -5.1321993), (-0.3386181, -5.701327), (-0.37045696, -6.34038), (-0.40544215, -6.94697), (-0.45580167, -7.711907), (-0.48936173, -8.165736), (-0.52177864, -8.558438), (-0.5721365, -9.112968), (-0.6326114, -9.723627), (-0.6764244, -10.130929), (-0.7162372, -10.471702), (-0.73864824, -11.2733345), (-0.6795322, -11.688038), (-0.6065086, -12.021755), (-0.52627456, -12.4043045), (-0.42850703, -13.172687), (-0.2827803, -15.462493), (-0.25139827, -16.006815), (-0.21802832, -16.84582)]
```

I want to check whether this tuple `(-0.405442, -6.94697)` is in `mylist` or not.

`(-0.40544215, -6.94697)` is in the list as shown below:

```
In [143]: mylist[13]
Out[143]: (-0.40544215, -6.94697)
```

But my query tuple has been somewhat truncated to `(-0.405442, -6.94697)`.

How may I let Python tell me that `(-0.405442, -6.94697)` is in `mylist` (ignore the truncating)?

Comment: `-0.40544215 != -0.405442`

Comment: @PauloBu  Shame on me. So sorry! But I never do truncate or that, why missed two decimal

Comment: I can't tell, I don't see any more code, as far as I concern you are the one trucating them when you specifically ask: `(-0.405442, -6.94697) in mylist` on the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(-0.405442, -6.94697)` is not in your list. `(-0.40544215, -6.94697)` is.

If you want to check if the tuples are in your list with an accuracy of 6 decimal digits, try this

```
(-0.405442, -6.94697) in [(round(i[0], 6), round(i[1], 6)) for i in mylist]
```

If you want to check this multiple times, your better off creating a new list though:

```
mynewlist = [(round(i[0], 6), round(i[1], 6)) for i in mylist]
(-0.405442, -6.94697) in mynewlist
```

Comment: (-0.405442, -6.94697) is not in your list. (-0.405442, -6.94697) is.???? Both are same what do you mean?

Comment: @Mutant: Typo, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Because (**-0.405442**, -6.94697) is not same as (**-0.40544215**, -6.94697)

```
>>> mylist=[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.769883), (-0.01435677, 1.7573411), (-0.3796871, -0.40361387), (-0.27704585, -1.7006601), (-0.26976547, -2.6480746), (-0.27020714, -3.0438666), (-0.2759932, -3.638946), (-0.28580084, -4.182567), (-0.29590216, -4.5594716), (-0.31486654, -5.1321993), (-0.3386181, -5.701327), (-0.37045696, -6.34038), (-0.40544215, -6.94697), (-0.45580167, -7.711907), (-0.48936173, -8.165736), (-0.52177864, -8.558438), (-0.5721365, -9.112968), (-0.6326114, -9.723627), (-0.6764244, -10.130929), (-0.7162372, -10.471702), (-0.73864824, -11.2733345), (-0.6795322, -11.688038), (-0.6065086, -12.021755), (-0.52627456, -12.4043045), (-0.42850703, -13.172687), (-0.2827803, -15.462493), (-0.25139827, -16.006815), (-0.21802832, -16.84582)]
>>> (-0.40544215, -6.94697) in mylist
True
```

*Unless its typo in question.

Comment: Sorry! No typo. Now I start wondering why there is a truncating. I never do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find approximate matches using comprehension, you can just check if the number is "close enough" to your desired value by checking if the absolute value of the number you want minus the number found is less than some limit, for example;

```
>>> [(x,y) for (x,y) in mylist if abs(-0.405442-x)<0.001 and abs(-6.94697-y)<0.001]

[(-0.40544215, -6.94697)]
```

...will find values that are within 0.001 of your desired values.